# Determine repeat characters in a php string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have found many examples of how to find repeat characters in a string. I believe my requirement is unique.

I have  string

```
$string=aabbbccddd;
```

I need to determine which character was repeated the most.
So for the above example it would say
The character repeated the most is "B".
However in the example above both B and D are repeated 3 times.
Would need to spot that. B AND D are both repeated 3 times.

This is what I have so far. FAR from what I need but starting point

```
    <?php
$string = "aabbbccddd";
$array=array($array);
foreach (count_chars($string, 1) as $i => $val) {
$count=chr($i);
$array[]= $val.",".$count;
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

Anyone have any thing that could help me?

Answer (score 6):

Based on georg's great point, I would use a regex.  This will handle split duplicates like `ddaaddd` with array keys `dd=>2` and `ddd=>3` but will only show one entry for `dd` when given `ddaadd`.  To represent both would require a more complex array:

```
$string = "ddaabbbccddda";
preg_match_all('/(.)\1+/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[0], array_map('strlen', $matches[0]));
arsort($result);
```

If you only need a count of ALL occurrences try:

```
$result = array_count_values(str_split($string));
arsort($result);
```

## Legacy Answers:

If you don't have split duplicates:

```
$string  = 'aabbbccddd';
$letters = str_split($string);
$result  = array_fill_keys($letters, 1);
$previous = '';

foreach($letters as $letter) {
    if($letter == $previous) {
        $result[$letter]++;
    }
    $previous = $letter;
}
arsort($result);
print_r($result);
```

Or for a regex approach:

```
preg_match_all('/(.)\1+/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], array_map('strlen', $matches[0]));
arsort($result);
```

Comment: I guess the input is not always sorted.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Your code assumes that the input string is always sorted and breaks otherwise (try `$string='dabdabdab'`).

Comment: Maybe I see your point: `ddaabbbccddd` you need to decide whether to just keep the 3 count of the `d` or have another array `$result['d'] = [2,3]`.  I would just use a regex, maybe I'll add it.

Comment: It might be that I misunderstood the question - are they looking for the longest sequence or just a char that appears the most? For the first case, your code works.

Comment: Added a new regex and left the rest for reference.

Comment: I don't think that this will do well with `abc`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's exactly what your looking for :

```
<?php
function printCharMostRepeated($str)
{
    if (!empty($str))
    {
        $max = 0;
        foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $key => $val)
            if ($max < $val) {
                $max = $val;
                $i = 0;
                unset($letter);
                $letter[$i++] = chr($key);
            } else if ($max == $val)
                $letter[$i++] = chr($key);
        if (count($letter) === 1)
            echo 'The character the most repeated is "'.$letter[0].'"';
        else if (count($letter) > 1) {
            echo 'The characters the most repeated are : ';
            $count = count($letter);
            foreach ($letter as $key => $value) {
                echo '"'.$value.'"';
                echo ($key === $count - 1) ? '.': ', ';
            }
        }
    } else
        echo 'value passed to '.__FUNCTION__.' can\'t be empty';
}

$str  = 'ddaabbccccsdfefffffqqqqqqdddaaa';
printCharMostRepeated($str);
```

Comment: This answering is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use count-chars()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

and then asort()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: Hi. My code is using count_chars() however im unsure how to manipulate the array to get a proper response.

Comment: use a sort and then loop though until the number you start with is less than the next number. so if the first number is 3, and the next is 2 thats it. but 3 3 2 gets the first 2

Comment: This counts ALL occurrences, not REPEATED occurrences.

Comment: At this point a example of how to do this for ALL occurrences is ok with me. I get the logic. I cant put it into PHP. Kind of new.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  $word = "abcdefghbi";

  for($i=0; $i<strlen($word);$i++){
      for($k=0;$k<strlen($word);$k++){
          if($word[$i] == $word[$k] && $i != $k){
              echo $word[$k]." is duplicate"; 
              exit;     
          }
    
      }
  }
  echo "no match found";
?>
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = "aabbbcccdddz";
$array = str_split($data);
$v = array_count_values($array);
foreach($v as $k => $val){ 
        echo $k.' = '.$val.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This does not determine the most occurring character.  This displays all unique characters snd their counts.